# TextBox.text only working followed by a Messagebox

Tags: c#, string, winforms, textbox, messagebox

All I want to do is to evaluate the X and Y values of the current mouse position with this simple code

```
 while (true)
            {
                textBox1.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString();
                //MessageBox.Show(""+Cursor.Position);
                Thread.Sleep(150);
            }
```

but it only seems to work when the MessageBox is uncommented otherwise it just writes nothing.

And if I initialize Cursor with a Panel.Handle it doesn't show the .position member;

Comment: So this is your whole program? And if the message box is shown the textBox1 is updated? Did you already try adding a breakpoint on the Sleep line and checking the value of the cursorPosition?

Comment: Thats the button_Click code. Yes if the messageBox is shown the textBox1 is updated. Already tried and Cursor.Position reads the right value the problem is writing it to textbox.

Comment: You should just subscribe to the MouseMove event on the form or panel and update the textbox from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is quite interesting. As you're using an endless loop, your form is never being updated (and either is your textbox). But if you add the messageBox, it seems as though the form is updated, if the messageBox is shown. So all you have to do is to put the endless loop into asynchronous context:

```
Task.Run(async () => await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString()));
            Thread.Sleep(150);
        }
    }));
```

You could achieve the same by using a timer:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var timer1 = new Timer
    {
        Enabled = true,
        Interval = 150
    };
    timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    timer1.Start();
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = Cursor.Position.X.ToString();
}
```

You should generally not use an endless loop on the main thread in forms applications, because otherwise your UI is freezing. Actually you could notice that I used `textBox1.Invoke` - this is there because you can't access UI elements on another thread than that they were created on.

A more elegant way to solve this however would be to handle the `MouseMove` event:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = $"Mouse location: {e.Location.X}, {e.Location.Y}";
}
```

I also changed the way the position is displayed (I used an *interpolated string*), as I think this is kind of more beautiful.

For more information on asynchronous programming take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/mt674882.aspx

Comment: ... or a timer.

Comment: But I don't reckon it's a better solution than the second one, so I don't think it's worth mentioning in this context.

Comment: I didn't say anything about better.  Just adding to your list.  If the mouse goes over a control, the form's MouseMove event won't fire.